# putting info from a text file into a table

Tags: bash

I'm trying to extract some info from a text log files (Bowtie2 sequencing aligner) and present them in a table. The text file looks like this:

```
Time loading reference: 00:00:00
Time loading forward index: 00:00:00
Time loading mirror index: 00:00:00
Multiseed full-index search: 00:21:50
3746112 reads; of these:
  3746112 (100.00%) were paired; of these:
    2937631 (78.42%) aligned concordantly 0 times
    581094 (15.51%) aligned concordantly exactly 1 time
    227387 (6.07%) aligned concordantly >1 times
    ----
    2937631 pairs aligned 0 times concordantly or discordantly; of these:
      5875262 mates make up the pairs; of these:
        5382980 (91.62%) aligned 0 times
        400492 (6.82%) aligned exactly 1 time
        91790 (1.56%) aligned >1 times
28.15% overall alignment rate
Time searching: 00:21:50
Overall time: 00:21:50
```

I've defines a few variables with the following commands, some of them have two strings, e.g., RDS_T is equal, in the following file to **3746112 (100.00%)**:

```
RDS_T=`awk NR==5 GW2.log | awk '{print $1}'` #total number of reads
RDS_P=`awk NR==6 GW2.log | awk '{print $1, $2}'` #Paired reads and percentage (2 fields)
RDS_C1=`awk NR==8 GW2.log | awk '{print $1, $2}'` #concordantly once and percentage (2 fields)
RDS_C2=`awk NR==9 GW2.log | awk '{print $1, $2}'` #concordantly twice and percentage (2 fields)
ALGN_T=`awk NR==16 GW2.log | awk '{print $1}'`
```

I used this to make a table but it doesn't work so nice:

```
printf "File\t Reads\t Paired reads\t Conc reads1\t Conc Reads2\t Total align\n\n\n GW1\t "%s$RDS_T\t" "%s" "$RDS_P"\t "%s" "$RDS_C1"\t "%s" "$RDS_C2"\t "%s$ALGN_T"\n"
```

Although separately, this ones work:

```
printf "%s$RDS_T
```

and

```
printf "%s" "$RDS_P"
```

one thing that I've noticed is that the \t is not interpreted

Any ideas how to do this, I'm quite new to bash so try to be gentle :)?

Thanks a lot,
Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `printf` correctly.

The usage of the `printf` command is: `printf format [arguments]`. (See the [`man`](http://ss64.com/bash/printf.html) page.)

For example:

```
printf "My name is %s. I live in %s.\n" "John" "London"
```

So, change your command to:

```
printf "File\tReads\tPaired reads\tConc reads1\tConc Reads2\tTotal align\nGW1\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$RDS_T" "$RDS_P" "$RDS_C1" "$RDS_C2" "$ALGN_T"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to call `awk` several times. You can do everything with a single `awk` script. Try the following command:

```
awk -f t.awk GW2.log
```

where `t.awk` is:

```
NR==5 {
    RDS_T=$1
}
NR==6 {
    RDS_P=$1" "$2
}
NR==8 {
    RDS_C1=$1" "$2
}
NR==9 {
    RDS_C2=$1" "$2
}
NR==16 {
    ALGN_T=$1
}

END {
    fmt="%-12s %-12s %-18s %-18s %-18s %-18s\n" 
    printf fmt, "File", "Reads", "Paired reads", "Conc reads1", "Conc Reads2", "Total align"
    printf fmt,  "GW2.log", RDS_T, RDS_P, RDS_C1, RDS_C2, ALGN_T
}
```

with output:

```
File         Reads        Paired reads       Conc reads1        Conc Reads2        Total align       
GW2.log      3746112      3746112 (100.00%)  581094 (15.51%)    227387 (6.07%)     28.15%
```

Comment: wowww, Thanks a lot for both of, second option worked straightforward so I'll stick to it!

Answer (score 0):

This is my final script, I've used dogbane option since I wanted to introduce a loop and have a single file (namely, no extra .awk file) but I didn't manage with Håkon Hægland method (though I'll be happy to learn how to do this with the current script). So the script will execute a Bowtie2 command for RNA-seq, generate the relevant directories and place each .sam and .log file (from each sequenced library) in these directories that are generated in the command. Last, the command will generate a small .txt table w/ some info from the .log files (e.g., total # of reads). I'm planning to try and complete the script such as it will also execute Tophat2, Cufflinks etc' and maybe will spit some info from these file such as graphs (using Cuffdif and Cummerband)

```
#!/bin/bash
#run from /rdata/ngseq/Playground/guy/bowtie2
#to execute run: /localhome/gw57/Notes/pipeline3.sh
#Generates a "Summary.txt" file from the GW files

INPUT=/rdata/ngseq/original_data/rna/illumina/2013-05-05_Guy #
DATE=$(date +%d%m%y) #needs to add hours when run more than once per day
ROOT=140213_root_No_8
BT2INDEX=Bowtie2Index_Arabidopsis/genome


for i in {1..4}
do
    if [ ! -d ./$ROOT ]
    then 
        mkdir ./$ROOT/
    fi

    if [ ! -d ./$ROOT/$DATE"_run" ]
    then
        mkdir ./$ROOT/$DATE"_run"
    fi

        mkdir ./$ROOT/$DATE"_run"/GW$i

        bowtie2 --local -q -5 30 -3 30 --phred33 -N 1 -L 10 --no-discordant -t --no-unal -p 12 -x $BT2INDEX -1\
         $INPUT/GW$i/fastq/R1.fastq -2 $INPUT/GW$i/fastq/R2.fastq\
          -S ./$ROOT/$DATE"_run"/GW$i/GW$i.sam 2>&1 | tee -a $ROOT/$DATE"_run"/GW$i/GW$i.log
done


printf "%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s\n\n"\
 "File" "Reads" "Paired_reads" "Conc Reads_once" "Conc_Reads>1" "Total_reads" > $ROOT/$DATE"_run"/Summary.txt

for i in {1..4}
do
    RDS_T=`awk 'NR==5 {print $1}' $ROOT/$DATE"_run"/GW$i/GW$i.log`
    RDS_P=`awk 'NR==6 {print $1, $2}' $ROOT/$DATE"_run"/GW$i/GW$i.log`
    RDS_C1=`awk 'NR==8 {print $1, $2}' $ROOT/$DATE"_run"/GW$i/GW$i.log`
    RDS_C2=`awk 'NR==9 {print $1, $2}' $ROOT/$DATE"_run"/GW$i/GW$i.log`
    ALGN_T=`awk 'NR==18 {print $1}' $ROOT/$DATE"_run"/GW$i/GW$i.log`

    printf "%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s\n" "GW$i" "$RDS_T" "$RDS_P" "$RDS_C1" "$RDS_C2" "$ALGN_T"
done >> $ROOT/$DATE"_run"/Summary.txt
```